# how to use Stripe (stripe.js) and react-native

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments

I'm trying to find a good approach to using stripe with react-native. Preferably one that doesn't involve sending credit card details to my own backend or storing my stripe private key in the application. Any ideas welcome! thanks

Comment: Are you trying to only use it to add credit cards for users or are you trying to do more with it?

Comment: For now just to add credit cards for the users - everything else i'm happy enough to hit my own backend, and from what I can tell, this is the recommended pattern from Stripe?

Comment: This is the way I have it setup in my app because to create actual transactions requires the private API key so I avoid sending that to client apps at all costs.

Comment: Yea - makes sense. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: The official Stripe node module (https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node) doesn't work with React-Native because it depends on the http module which RN does not have. This blog post offers one solution: http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html and there is another module at https://github.com/llanox/react-native-stripe-wrapper/ which helps, but neither approach is nearly as simple as stripe.js.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have not implemented this in React Native personally yet. In the app I am working on this will be ported over in the next few days but here is how we do it in the current app without any dependency on third party libraries and how we will implement in React Native as well. This is obviously just a concept that can be used anywhere you can make a HTTP call.

Make a POST call to https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens with a 'Authorization' header with the value `Bearer {PUBLISHABLE_AUTH_TOKEN}`. In the body `(x-www-form-urlencoded)` put:

```
card[name]={NAME_ON_CARD}&card[number]={CARD_NUMBER}&card[exp_month]={CARD_EXP_MONTH}&card[exp_year]={CARD_EXP_YEAR}&card[cvc]={CARD_CVC}
```

The response will be a JSON object that contains (among other things) an id field. This id field is what you will reference the card when making transactions so this ID needs sent to your server and stored. This ID can be stored without worry of PCI compliance.

More Info: https://stripe.com/docs/api#tokens

Comment: Hello. I came across this while trying to figure out how to implement Stripe in React Native. If you can take a look at this question, I would greatly appreciate it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092731/how-to-implement-stripe-with-react-native Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you can make some time to chat via here, I would really appreciate it. Currently in the process of integrating Stripe into React Native, and would like to clear some things up. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is fantastic. How can I then finalize the payment in the same manner? What route is called, with what parameters and so on?

Answer (score 10):

I recommend: https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

I was able to successfully connect React Native and Stripe to create a customer and add a card and save the tokens to my back end.

Comment: How did you add the card to the customer? From RN side itself or by passing a token to your backend?

Comment: @SuhairZain - passing token to backend.

Comment: well, the ux of this wrapper is quite bad actually when compared with 
https://github.com/sonnylazuardi/react-native-credit-card

There has no transition or indicator to tell which type of card is selected.

Comment: I'm uneasy using a third-party library to handle payments, but I'll do it just to get things moving and maybe switch later. Kinda ridiculous how Stripe's JS library doesn't work in React Native. Maybe they'll fix it like Google did with Firebase JS.

Comment: Beau Smith how did handle backend of stripe in react native ?   i have token generated but i don't know what to do now ?

Comment: @MuhammadAshfaq - You'll need to read the Stripe docs for how to handle tokens from the backend, it's more than can be summarized in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure, but what We want to achieve is simple.

With react, we were able to achieve this by calling stripe from the front end for card information. However, React Native does not have its own code.

So we need to get everything we need from by ourself Like this

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
  -u sk_test_IjzBJWterND0tgdSyEIhDmgS00ODHLjw1a: \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=7 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2021 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
```

and you will get

```
% curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/tokens \
  -u sk_test_IjzBJWterND0tgdSyEIhDmgS00ODHLjw1a: \
  -d "card[number]"=4242424242424242 \
  -d "card[exp_month]"=7 \
  -d "card[exp_year]"=2021 \
  -d "card[cvc]"=314
{
  "id": "tok_1H2Vt9AxSyQJWoao8qhjHDuh",
  "object": "token",
  "card": {
    "id": "card_1H2Vt9AxSyQJWoao26em4Dps",
    "object": "card",
    "address_city": null,
    "address_country": null,
    "address_line1": null,
    "address_line1_check": null,
    "address_line2": null,
    "address_state": null,
    "address_zip": null,
    "address_zip_check": null,
    "brand": "Visa",
    "country": "US",
    "cvc_check": "unchecked",
    "dynamic_last4": null,
    "exp_month": 7,
    "exp_year": 2021,
    "fingerprint": "IS61beTzZemIdd8p",
    "funding": "credit",
    "last4": "4242",
    "metadata": {
    },
    "name": null,
    "tokenization_method": null
  },
  "client_ip": "153.218.66.247",
  "created": 1594186331,
  "livemode": false,
  "type": "card",
  "used": false
}
```

You can use the `tok_` on the card to implement backend charges as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into issues doing this with existing libraries, so I wrote a better one. [react-native-stripe](https://github.com/lrettig/react-native-stripe) allows you to collect credit card information, validate it using Stripe, and exchange it for a Stripe token, all using native code. Currently iOS only.