# How to implement Stripe with React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, stripe-payments, fetch-api

I have researched on how to implement Stripe using React native, but have not found a solid way to so. Apparently, React Native does not support http module so would have to use Stripe API using `fetch` (as explained in http://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/11/03/using-stripe-api-in-react-native-with-fetch.html).

So my question is, is using fetch method to Stripe API endpoints a good alternative to `stripe.js`? And would I be missing out on anything by not using `stripe.js`? Also, is `stripe.js` another name for the Stripe SDK?

Lastly, by using fetch to Stripe API endpoints in place of `stripe.js`, would it still be considered a fully PCI-compliant integration as described in https://stripe.com/docs/security ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use Stripe (stripe.js) and react-native](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34467260/how-to-use-stripe-stripe-js-and-react-native)

Answer (score 16):

We've made wrapper around native Stripe SDK for both platforms here: https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe

When you are using native sdk it gives you better integration with platform, so our goal was to make same api for both platforms and support native features.

Comment: Is there a plan to include bank account/ACH in this wrapper?

Comment: Does this support the universal windows platform as well?

Comment: No, there are no native windows bindings. I believe, you may use tipsi.js on windows

Comment: Hi @cybergrind I`m using your tipsi-stripe module.And Is it only for generating a Token? Can we update Card details using it?

Comment: Hey @BuwanekaSumanasekara. I'm not sure what you really can update in card details in general. I believe you can find out more information here - https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards - you can use token to save cards for further payments.

Comment: Hi @cybergrind, I am trying to create new source object through tipsi-stripe (v 5.6.0) with card details but I am not able to do so. The method 'createSourceWithParams' accepts card Id but not the card details, so I tried to create card Id by calling  'paymentRequestWithCardForm' method. When I create source with 'createSrcWithParams' with cardId and type 'card' (as per docs), I get error- 'type' being incorrect. Any idea about this? I was going to post separate question on SOF but thought to do more research on this and found this PR https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/pull/261 (open?)

Comment: Is this package still maintained?

Comment: @Muhammad only by the community because Tipsi don't use RN anymore, there is no dedicated people. Stripe wanted to adopt it but they haven't done it yet.

Comment: If anyone wants to get it rolling: https://github.com/tipsi/tipsi-stripe/pull/532#issuecomment-538760406

Comment: @cybergrind Do you have credit card save fracture in the tipsi-stripe